# Exiting: Error importing Kibana dashboards: fail to create the Elasticsearch loader: Elasticsearch output is not configured/enabled

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

Struggling to get filebeat working.

According to the docs (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.1/load-kibana-dashboards.html) dashboard loading is required.

So, in `/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml`

```
setup.dashboards.enabled: true
```

but now I get:

```
beat.go:625: CRIT Exiting: Error importing Kibana dashboards: fail to create the Elasticsearch loader: Elasticsearch output is not configured/enabled
Exiting: Error importing Kibana dashboards: fail to create the Elasticsearch loader: Elasticsearch output is not configured/enabled
```

I was under the impression that Logstash output is all that's required and that Logstash takes care of output to Elasticsearch.

However, if I enable Elasticsearch output in filebeat (`/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml`):

```
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
```

I get:

```
beat.go:625: CRIT Exiting: error unpacking config data: more then one namespace configured accessing 'output' (source:'/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml')
Exiting: error unpacking config data: more then one namespace configured accessing 'output' (source:'/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your configuration but it seems you set 2 different outputs for Filebeat, This service accepts only one output, Just comment the other one (ex: output.elasticsearch). And then check the config file again:

```
filebeat -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
```